# Invalid error message format

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, error-message

Prior signing the mod agreement attempting to forcibly accept a tag synonym leads to an error with an incorrectly formatted message:

> [image]

The useful part of this message states:

> You must accept the Moderator Agreement; click the mod link

Looks like devs forgot to use only text part of the message and accidentally use the whole JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report! I've fixed this (the problem was as you described), so it should show up properly now as the actual response text instead of the full JSON. Let me know if this doesn't fix the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issue. To test it I have to resign moderator agreement or win election on other site. On the other hand it may lead to one more [most downvoted post published by me ever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/339911).