# Moderator agreement acceptance notice should be made translatable

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, moderator-agreement

On [moderator agreement page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) the notice about accepting should be made translatable.

> [image]

This is not a part of legal agreement (that is not a subject for translation), and the date inside notice already has localized format.

Related: [How can I ask a question regarding moderator related issues if I don't have access to the Teachers' Lounge or the Stack Moderators team?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/339911)